# How do make columns in a grid "space-evenly" like with flexbox?

Tags: css, css-grid, grid-layout

I have this grid CSS

```css
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-column-gap: 50px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}
```

which is sitting in a div with width: 500px

but I noticed that the first item in the grid "hugs" the left edge of the div but the far most right item doesn't touch the edge of the div.

In flexbox I could achieve this with (near enough):

```css
.flex {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
 }
```

how do I do this responsively with the grid?

I know I can change the grid-column-gap but that seems flakey

Comment: you should try `gap`

Comment: also `justify-content: space-between;` it does work with CSS grid

Comment: CSS-Tricks: [`justify-content`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/#aa-justify-content)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `auto` instead of `1fr` and the same `justify-content` will work like with flexbox:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-column-gap: 50px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
  justify-content:space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>aaa</div>
  <div>bbb</div>
  <div>ccc</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);` can safely be replaced by `grid-auto-flow: column;` then, right?

Comment: @connexo yes if you want only one row but not if you want more elements (more rows) and still keep 3 columns

Answer (score 2):

Consider using `auto-fit` keyword to fit columns into the available row space by expanding them.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
</div>
```